# if else statement inside if else ternary statement in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement

I have a case where i need to specify

```
if (_amplifyConifured) {
  if (_isUserIsLoggedIn) {
    return DashboardScreen.routeName;
  } else {
    return LoginScreen.routeName;
  }
} else {
  LoadingScreen.routeName;
}
```

Tried this:

```
 _amplifyConfigured ? 
          _isUserIsLoggedIn ? DashboardScreen.routeName : LoginScreen.routeName :
          LoginScreen.routeName : LoadingScreen.routeName
```

But it's not throwing error

Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try, you used one statement more

```
_amplifyConfigured ? 
          _isUserIsLoggedIn ? DashboardScreen.routeName : LoginScreen.routeName : LoadingScreen.routeName
```

Comment: thanks Error is gone but when _isUserIsLoggedIn is true it shows LoginScreen

Comment: but `_isUserIsLoggedIn` is true it should display the `DashboardScreen.routeName`, you can check your code is `_isUserIsLoggedIn ` is true or false?. Otherwise refresh your ide

Answer (score 0):

```
_amplifyConifured?
  _isUserIsLoggedIn? 
     DashboardScreen.routeName:  
      LoginScreen.routeName:
LoadingScreen.routeName;
```

Comment: Thanks. But screen now only shows loadingScreen even though both are true

Comment: Can you try with `flutter clean` and rebuild again, I mean how it even possible, also can you check where you are applying it? Also make sure state management property.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh but you missed the ` LoginScreen.routeName` statement in your code

Comment: Thanks, my bad. Mixed with `LoadingScreen` and `LoginScreen`

Comment: it's my pleasure

Comment: LoginScreen Is missing?

Comment: Consider @Jahidul Islam's answer.